# Can a given vector be expressed in bases of different span?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, change-of-basis

$\mathbf{M}$ is $n$-x-$n$ symmetric p.d., $\mathbf{Q}$ is $n$-x-$d$ (with $d<n$), and $\mathbf{u}$ is a $d$-x-$1$ vector.  The columns of $\mathbf{Q}$ are linearly independent.  Another $d$-x-$1$ vector $\mathbf{v}$ can be expressed as follows:

$$\mathbf{MQu=v}$$

The full rank matrix $\mathbf{M}$ can be considered an $n$-dimensional basis for $\mathbf{v}$ with coefficients $\mathbf{Qu}$.

$$\sum^n_{i=1}\mathbf{m}_i x_i=\mathbf{v}$$

(where $\mathbf{m}_i$ is the ith column of $\mathbf{M}$ and $x_i\in \mathbf{x=Qu}=\mathbf{q}_1 u_1+\mathbf{q}_2 u_2+...+\mathbf{q}_d u_d$)

But since the columns $\mathbf{q}_i\in\mathbf{Q}$ are known to be linearly independent, $\mathbf{MQ}$ can also be considered a $d$-dimensional basis for $\mathbf{v}$ with coefficients $\mathbf{u}$.

$$\sum^d_{i=1}\mathbf{Mq}_i u_i=\mathbf{v}$$

The first basis is full rank, while the second basis is rank deficient.

1) I was under the impression that a given vector $\mathbf{v}$ can be expressed in any basis, but that the dimension of the linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by any such given basis remains the same.  Here it seems that $\mathbf{v}$ can be expressed either in a basis spanning $d$ dimensions of $\mathbb{R}^n$, or a full rank basis spanning all $n$ of it.  How to conceptually reconcile a vector that can be expressed in bases of different dimension?

2) Which basis should I use?  Is one more useful or "correct" than the other?  Or does it basically not matter?

Comment: A basis is defined w.r.t a vector space and not a vector. The $n$ and $d$ dimensional bases are for different vector spaces. Consider for example a vector $v$ parallel to $e_1$ in the $e_1-e_2$ plane. $v = ae_1$ but also $v=ae_1+0e_2$

Comment: Which basis you want to use is often a matter of purpose; there is no globally correct answer.  Sometimes a basis will be chosen as it allows for rapid computation of the action of a specific matrix.  Other times a 'standard' basis will be used to allow the reader to better 'see' the vector.